# How to Clearly Plot a Plane in 3D in Lecture Notes

Tags: graphing-functions, 3d, lecture-notes

I'm currently teaching introductory linear algebra. This is my first time as the instructor, but I have been a teaching assistant for the class before.

A recurring problem I have is drawing a clear plot of a plane that passes through the origin.

In my lecture today, I drew a plot like this (although this is cleaned up---the version in the lecture was quite bad):

[image]

Even looking at it myself, I find it difficult to parse which lines are where. I'd love to hear some advice on how to make this more clear.

For context, the equation for the plane is
$$ \mathcal{P} := \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R} \mid z = ax + by + c\},$$
with $a = 1/2$, $b = 1$, and $c=0$.

Comment: A good 3D perception is brought by *animation* (which can be done with Geogebra or Desmos). The problem with "overloading" the plane with lines with different colors may "saturate" observers, especialy those who haven't a good natural 3D perception.

Comment: That's a great point. If do need to draw it by hand, drawing the edges of a square might be a better approach than drawing the whole grid.